Need desperate help with Binary Bomb Lab phase 1
I desperately need help with Phase 1 of this Binary Bomb(Reverse Engineering assignment for coding students). It's a little different than other binary bombs so I'm not able to find help anywhere else online. I believe I need to input 2 integers, and I think one of those integers would be 319 but I'm not sure. This is the assembly dump for Phase 1.
Dump of assembler code for function phase_1:
=> 0x0000555555556627 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x000055555555662b <+4>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000055555555662f <+8>: mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000555555556638 <+17>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x000055555555663d <+22>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000055555555663f <+24>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rcx
   0x0000555555556644 <+29>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x0000555555556647 <+32>:    lea    0x1d8f(%rip),%rsi        # 0x5555555583dd
   0x000055555555664e <+39>:    call   0x555555556330 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x0000555555556653 <+44>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000555555556656 <+47>:    jle    0x55555555667d <phase_1+86>
   0x0000555555556658 <+49>:    mov    (%rsp),%eax
   0x000055555555665b <+52>:    mov    0x4(%rsp),%edx
   0x000055555555665f <+56>:    cmp    %edx,%eax
   0x0000555555556661 <+58>:    je     0x555555556684 <phase_1+93>
   0x0000555555556663 <+60>:    mov    (%rsp),%esi
   0x0000555555556666 <+63>:    mov    0x4(%rsp),%ecx
   0x000055555555666a <+67>:    mov    $0x0,%r8d
   0x0000555555556670 <+73>:    mov    $0x0,%r9d
   0x0000555555556676 <+79>:    mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x000055555555667b <+84>:    jmp    0x5555555566a7 <phase_1+128>
   0x000055555555667d <+86>:    call   0x555555556ee4 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000555555556682 <+91>:    jmp    0x555555556658 <phase_1+49>
   0x0000555555556684 <+93>:    call   0x555555556ee4 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000555555556689 <+98>:    mov    (%rsp),%eax
   0x000055555555668c <+101>:   mov    0x4(%rsp),%ecx
   0x0000555555556690 <+105>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000555555556692 <+107>:   je     0x5555555566c5 <phase_1+158>
   0x0000555555556694 <+109>:   mov    %ecx,%edx
   0x0000555555556696 <+111>:   jmp    0x555555556663 <phase_1+60>
   0x0000555555556698 <+113>:   sub    %edx,%eax
   0x000055555555669a <+115>:   mov    %eax,%esi
   0x000055555555669c <+117>:   mov    %edi,%r8d
   0x000055555555669f <+120>:   cmp    %esi,%ecx
   0x00005555555566a1 <+122>:   je     0x5555555566b4 <phase_1+141>
   0x00005555555566a3 <+124>:   mov    %ecx,%edx
   0x00005555555566a5 <+126>:   mov    %esi,%eax
   0x00005555555566a7 <+128>:   cmp    %edx,%eax
   0x00005555555566a9 <+130>:   jge    0x555555556698 <phase_1+113>
   0x00005555555566ab <+132>:   mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x00005555555566ad <+134>:   sub    %eax,%ecx
   0x00005555555566af <+136>:   mov    %edi,%r9d
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
   0x00005555555566b2 <+139>:   jmp    0x55555555669f <phase_1+120>
   0x00005555555566b4 <+141>:   test   %r8b,%r8b
   0x00005555555566b7 <+144>:   je     0x5555555566bc <phase_1+149>
   0x00005555555566b9 <+146>:   mov    %esi,(%rsp)
   0x00005555555566bc <+149>:   test   %r9b,%r9b
   0x00005555555566bf <+152>:   je     0x5555555566c5 <phase_1+158>
   0x00005555555566c1 <+154>:   mov    %ecx,0x4(%rsp)
   0x00005555555566c5 <+158>:   cmp    $0x13f,%ecx
   0x00005555555566cb <+164>:   jne    0x5555555566e2 <phase_1+187>
   0x00005555555566cd <+166>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555566d2 <+171>:   sub    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00005555555566db <+180>:   jne    0x5555555566e9 <phase_1+194>
   0x00005555555566dd <+182>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00005555555566e1 <+186>:   ret    
   0x00005555555566e2 <+187>:   call   0x555555556ee4 <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555566e7 <+192>:   jmp    0x5555555566cd <phase_1+166>
   0x00005555555566e9 <+194>:   call   0x555555556280 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
End of assembler dump.


please refine your question, what do you need help with? we may help or redirect you to the other stackexchange sites

Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79296273 where a reviewer suggested looking here for existing questions about bomb labs.  There are none because reverse engineering is must more about the engineering than any theoretical CS stuff.  The math or linked-list-following or table-lookup or whatever problem is usually the easy part, it's figuring out exactly what the function is doing to get to the CS part that's the challenge.  Questions about defusing binary bombs belong on Stack Overflow where we have a tag for it.  (@RinkeshP).

Correction, this was posted first, before the Stack Overflow question which is about phase 4; this was phase 1.  (And has a couple details about constraints on the input values reverse-engineered from the code for that phase).

This phase 1 is less trivial than some of the phase 1s I've seen, but yeah it's still just checking things about 2 integers.  I'd start by commenting next to the code tracing what values are in which register, and which blocks jump where so you can turn it into some structured if() conditions.  Or look for a path of branching that gets to the ret without hitting explode_bomb, and see which way branches need to go.

A disassembler like objconv that labels branch targets can be helpful; otherwise you'd only notice that by looking at the addresses (or the offsets in GDB's disassembly, like <+120>. Yes, you need 319 in ECX when cmp    $0x13f,%ecx runs, but that might be a subtraction result.  There is a sub instruction with an ECX destination.  Oh, and it appears to be inside a loop, since there's a backwards jmp right after it, and only conditional branches before reaching it again.

jmp backwards to a cmp/jcc out of the loop looks like a while() compiled with minimal optimization, like GCC -O1
